# Scaling sql database on azure. Is data loss possible?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an sql database on azure, My service tier is standard, I already scaled data max size to 500GB (standard tier is 200GB by default). Now I want to scale it to 750GB. I read documentaion but I'm not sure. How long it will take and if any data loss is possible ? Also will I have to change my configuration or all connection string etc stays the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data loss is not a byproduct of changing performance tiers or storage size, no.  In most of the standard tiers, you are running on remote storage (similar to how SQL Server in a VM would run over blob storage backed disks).  So, if all you are doing is increasing the max size on remote storage, that's morally equivalent to the same operation on-premises and it is immediate.  If you are crossing tiers (say, standard to premium) or within premium tiers where there is no space available on the local nodes to satisfy your requests, the operation can take time since new space needs to be provisioned and your database needs to be seeded (copied) into the new space.  This is done in the background and is related to the size of your database, the performance tier (as IOPS are based on that), and the current transaction load (as this also has to be replicated to N new nodes).  When things are replicated and up-to-date, your current connections are closed from the server (which means any active transactions there are aborted) and you can reconnect and retry those on the newly seeded database replicas.  This usually takes minutes to tens of minutes but for very large databases it can take an hour or longer.